# split elements string in R by pattern and length before end

Tags: r, string, split

I want to split all elements in 'a', at 'B' and at 3 values before the end of the string. The output should be a similar object (character) as 'a' with the shorter elements.

```
a <- c("A122.B551.ytzuZZZ", "A78.B619.triXXX")

#"B551.ytzu" "B619.tri"
```

Comment: What is the desired output? It is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working for your given cases:

```
gsub("^.*(B.*).{3}$", "\\1", a)
# [1] "B551.ytzu" "B619.tri"
```

where `^` matches the beginning of the string, `.*` match any number of characters. `(B.*)` will match a pattern starting from B until three characters before the end of string denoted by `.{3}$`. `\\1` replace the string with the pattern `(B.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries devoted to editing strings and lots of functions in base. Functions to start with `substr()`,`gsub()`,`strsplit()`.  Then move on to `grep()`, `regexpr()`, `regexec()`. And finally consider the package `stringr`.

Of these, `gsub()` is frequently sufficient.

```
a <- c("A122.B551.ytzuZZZ", "A78.B619.triXXX")

# Remove everything up to B with just B.  (see '?grep' for what "^.*" means).

a2<-gsub("^.*B","B",a)

# Remove the last three characters (see '?grep' for what ".{3}$" means).

a3<-gsub(".{3}$","",a2)
```